# removing spaces in nvl function in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am using nvl function to show nothing in place of null

```
             nvl(test,' ')
             | |
             currently spaces are coming i want this
             ||
```

Comment: this func write null

Comment: Helpful information would be: what is the input string, how does it look like, how should it look like etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `' '` with `''`:

```
nvl(test,'')
```

- See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/2378).